# main application locks up using idPop3 to retrieve mail messages (even in a thread)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-2010

I am using a thread to access a pop3 account and retrieve messages. It works fine, but it locks up my application until it is complete. Cant move the window, shut down, click buttons, nothing.

It runs fine and allows me to access the main application up until the spot i commented out (or after the IdPOP31.Connect();)

//Getting the number of the messages that server has

then it locks up

```
procedure TPopThread.Pop;
var
 vName, vEmail, vServerIn, vServerOut, vUserId, vPassword: String;
 vPop3Port, vSMTPPort, vSSL: String; vHTML: TStringList;
   MsgCount : Integer;
   i,j        : Integer;
   FMailMessage :  TIdMessage;
begin
   with frmMain do
   begin
   RzMemo1.Lines.Clear;
   vHTML:= TStringList.Create;
   GetAccount(lbxMain.SelectedItem,vName, vEmail, vServerIn, vServerOut, vUserId, vPassword,
   vPop3Port, vSMTPPort, vSSL, vHTML);
   IdPOP31.Host      := vServerIn;
   IdPOP31.Username  := vUserId;
   IdPOP31.Password  := vPassword;
   IdPOP31.Port      := StrToInt(vPop3Port);

  try
     Prepare(IdPOP31);
     IdPOP31.Connect();
//   {
//   //Getting the number of the messages that server has.
//   MsgCount := IdPOP31.CheckMessages;
//   for i:= 0 to Pred(MsgCount) do
//   begin
//     try
//       FMailMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
//       IdPOP31.Retrieve(i,FMailMessage);
//       RzMemo1.Lines.Add('=================================================');
//       RzMemo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.From.Address);
//       RzMemo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses);
//       RzMemo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Subject);
//       RzMemo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Sender.Address);
//       RzMemo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Body.Text);
//
//       for J := 0 to Pred( FMailMessage.MessageParts.Count ) do
//       begin
//        // if the part is an attachment
//        if ( FMailMessage.MessageParts.Items[ J ] is TIdAttachment) then
//        begin
//         RzMemo1.Lines.Add('Attachment: ' + TIdAttachment(FMailMessage.MessageParts.Items[J]).Filename);
//        end;
//       end;
//       RzMemo1.Lines.Add('=================================================');
//     finally
//       FMailMessage.Free;
//     end;
//     RzMemo1.Clear;
//   end;
//   }
   finally
     IdPOP31.Disconnect;
     vHTML.Free;
   end;
   end;
end;
```

It actually did this before I added the thread, so it has something to do with that portion that is commented out and not the thread

What did i do wrong or didn't do?

here is my Execute

```
procedure TPopThread.Execute;
begin
  try
    Synchronize(Pop);
  except
    on Ex: Exception do
      fExceptionMessage := Ex.Message;
  end;
end;
```

here is how i call it

```
PopThread := TPopThread.Create(lbxMain.SelectedItem, frmMain.DonePopping);
```

Comment: You cannot access any part of the VCL (any visual components) from a secondary thread. They should be used only in the main thread. You're accessing `RzMemo1` from your thread code. Please read the **large** comment block at the start of a new `TThread` unit (File->New->Other->TThread Object) about using `Synchronize`, or see the sample for threadng that comes with every version of Delphi since TThread was introduced in Delphi 2.

Comment: please show the Execute method of your TPopThread (assuming TPopThread is derived from TThread), if Pop is not called from within Execute then its not actually running in a new thread anyway.  Also as Ken has written the VLC is not thread safe

Comment: 'it locks up my application until it is complete' - that is the expected behaviour if you call Pop from a main VCL thread event-handler.  Then see the other stuff posted by Ken/Damp for some of the wrong things you are doing when trying to thread this off.

Comment: I have redited the main post to show my execute method. However, as I stated, regardless of whether or not I use the thread, it locks my app up at the noted spot in the code

Comment: Youv'e synchronized your Pop function which will make in run in the Main thread thus defeating the whole object of creating the TPopThread in the first place

Comment: OK, so do you have a solution for me. I am a novice to threads. Please advise - but it still does not answer the question of why it does the locking of the application even if I do not use a thread

Comment: Most Indy Clients are blocking so the the calls to .connect .checkmessage and .retieve of your TIDPop3 object wont return until they have completed the required communcations with the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *locking up* the application yourself, because you're [synchronizing](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) the call to the pop method.

> Synchronize causes the call specified by AMethod to be **executed using the main thread**, thereby avoiding multithread conflicts.
>
> The current thread is passed in the AThread parameter.
>
> If you are unsure whether a method call is thread-safe, call it from within the Synchronize method to ensure it executes in the main thread.
>   Execution of the current thread is suspended while the method executes in the main thread.

So, for practical purposes, you're like you have no extra thread, since all your code is executed in the main thread.

> An example of when you would want to use Synchronize is when you want to **interact with a VCL component**

On the other hand, because you're directly accessing a number of visual controls from your method, and the VCL is not thread safe, you have to execute your method in the main thread.

The best you can do is to make your thread independent from the VCL by not accessing any VCL component from the thread, but rather collecting all the input and output values in memory and setting/reading it from the main thread before the thread starts and after the thread finishes.

Or, if for any reason you don't want to do that, you can dissect your method to separate the parts that need access to the VCL and synchronize only that parts, for example:

```
type
  TPopThread = class
  private
    FMailMessage :  TIdMessage;  //now the message belongs to the class itself

  ...
  public
    //all the values are passed via constructor or the thread is 
    //created in suspended state, configured and then started
    property Host: string read FHost write FHost;
    property UserName: string read FUserName write FUserName;
    property Password: string read ...;
    property Port: Integer read ...;
  end;

procedure TPopThread.CopyMailToGUI;
var
  J: Integer;
begin
  frmMain.RzMemo1.Lines.Add('=================================================');
  frmMain.RzMemo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.From.Address);
  frmMain.RzMemo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses);
  frmMain.RzMemo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Subject);
  frmMain.RzMemo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Sender.Address);
  frmMain.RzMemo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Body.Text);

  for J := 0 to Pred( FMailMessage.MessageParts.Count ) do
  begin
    // if the part is an attachment
    if ( FMailMessage.MessageParts.Items[ J ] is TIdAttachment) then
    begin
      frmMain.RzMemo1.Lines.Add('Attachment: ' + TIdAttachment(FMailMessage.MessageParts.Items[J]).Filename);
    end;
  end;
  frmMain.RzMemo1.Lines.Add('=================================================');
end;

procedure TPopThread.Pop;
var
  MsgCount : Integer;
  i,j        : Integer;
  Pop: TIdPOP3;
begin
  Pop := TIdPOP3.Create(nil);
  try
    Pop.Host      := FHost;
    Pop.Username  := FUserName;
    Pop.Password  := FPassword;
    Pop.Port      := FPort;
    Prepare(Pop);
    Pop.Connect();
    //Getting the number of the messages that server has.
    MsgCount := Pop.CheckMessages;
    for I := 0 to Pred(MsgCount) do
    begin
      try
        FMailMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
        try
          IdPOP31.Retrieve(i,FMailMessage);
          Synchronize(CopyMailToGUI);
        finally
          FMailMessage.Free;
        end;
    end;
  finally
    Pop.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TPopThread.Execute;
begin
  //no need of a try/except, if an exception occurs, it 
  //is stored in the FatalException property
  Pop;
end;
```

Now, your thread will *ask* the main thread to *copy* just the processed message to the VCL. During that *copy* your thread will block and your application will not respond to messages because the main thread is busy, but that will be for very shorts intervals, so even if it is not the ideal case, I think it will work for what you want.

Comment: +1 should give Johnny a very goot starting point, though I would use and OnRxdMessage event in CopyMailToGui just to remove the link to the MainForm.

Comment: @Dampsquid yes, events is the way to go, but I didn't want to complicate the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You put all your logic inside a `Synchronize` call. `Synchronize` runs its function in the main VCL thread, so you've essentially nullified any benefits you might have gained from using a separate thread in the first place.

Remove the call to `Synchronize` so that `Pop` runs in the thread you created for it.

If you still need some operations to execute in the main thread, then put them in subroutines so that you can run *only them* in `Synchronize`. The parts I see in that code are the places where you add lines to a memo control.